# netsuite :Specify expense and income accounts for this item

Tags: netsuite, items

I try creating an item in nesuite with java script and got the following error :
You must specify expense and income accounts for this item.

However is I load an already existing item from netsuite
var myItem =  nlapiLoadRecord('noninventoryitem',2049);
var expenseaccount =  myItem.getFieldValue('expenseaccount');

it sets the value of expense account as null.

I can create an item via interface that does not have accounts specified but not via script.

The item I am trying to create is a non inventory for sale item.

Thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the 'subtype' field on the record before saving it.  If you do not set a value for this field, NetSuite must be thinking that it is a Non-Inventory Item for ReSale which needs an expense and income account.

Also is the item you are loading in your code a Non-Inventory Item For Sale?  If yes, that might explain why the 'expenseaccount' field is blank/null.

Comment: While creating the item i am using the following script :

var rec = nlapiCreateRecord('noninventoryitem');
rec.setFieldValue('itemid','Test Sale-1');
rec.setFieldValue('taxschedule',1);
rec.setFieldValue('incomeaccount',54);
rec.setFieldValue('subtype','Sale');
var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(rec);
Also as mentioned above the itesm that are being loaded are non inventory sale items.